# Sum two complex selection

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I am looking for sum these two selection but I don't know how to do. Could you help me please ?

```html
$score_selection = "SELECT user_ID, Sum(approval_rate) AS total_approval FROM comments GROUP BY user_ID ORDER BY total_approval DESC";
 $score_result = mysqli_query ($connect,$score_selection) ;

 while ($comment_score = mysqli_fetch_array($score_result)) { 
  $user_ID = $comment_score['user_ID'] ;
  $comment_score = $comment_score['total_approval'] ;
    
    $score_checked_query = "SELECT user_score FROM user_score WHERE user_ID='$user_ID'" ;
   $score_checked_result = mysqli_query ($connect,$score_checked_query) ;

   while ($score = mysqli_fetch_array($score_checked_result)) {
   $user_score = $score['user_score'] ;



   echo "($user_score+$comment_score) point(s) </br>" ;
      
      <?php
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: simple use join

Answer (score 0):

simple use  **JOIN**  No need multiple query

```
SELECT c.user_ID, sum(c.approval_rate+u.user_score) AS total_approval 
FROM comments AS c 
JOIN user_score AS u 
ON u.user_ID=c.user_ID 
GROUP BY c.user_ID 
ORDER BY total_approval DESC
```

Comment: Sorry but your indication give to me a wrong sum :/

Comment: wrong sum .can you please provide sample data for both table @AdouPro

Comment: Don't worry Jyo. I find an alternate solution. Thank you :)